# Change the order of columns in css

Tags: html, css

i have very much struggling on change order of column and rows. Please anyone know solve this problems.

```
Before

1 2 3
4 5 6

I need like this

1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Comment: what have you tried ? how your html looks like? are u using float -flexbox-inline-block ... ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

What i understand is that you want to display text in 2 columns, here is an example of how to do that using css + html :

```
<div>
 <span>1</span>
 <span>2</span>
 <span>3</span>
 <span>4</span>
 <span>5</span>
 <span>6</span>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div {
-webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
column-count: 2;
width: 35px;
}
```